# How to ignore message window when range.replace method not found?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using vba to write a batch replace script.
But the warnning message window always pop up everytime the search string not found,it makes me have to close it again and again.Is it possible to hide this window?

```
targetRng.Replace s, s.Offset(0, 1)
```

[image]

this pic mainly says search string not found,xxxxxxxxx

Comment: Please provide a full working minimal example that produces the error. We can not do much with one line of code. I don't get any messages if the string is not found with the line above! Everything looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to prevent Excel showing any alerts.

Don't forget to turn it on afterwards with `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`.